# Counting the number of hyperlink in a table

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a dynamic web table and I want to count the hyperlinks in the table using Javascript.

Here is the HTML:

```
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td style="..."
         <a id =" " href="test1">123456</a>
        </td>
        <td style="..."
         <a id =" " href="test2">123477</a>
        </td>
        <<td style="..."
         <a id =" " href="test3">1234557</a>
        </td>
```

I want to get the count of the href from this HTML

This is what i have tried so far:

```
    Function Rowcount(){
        var totalRowCount=0;
//identifying the table
        var table=document.getElementById("tableID");
//identifying the row
        var rows=table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var tdata=null;
        for( var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){

           tdata=rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")

        }
    }
```

I am not understanding how should I refer to "href"

Comment: the tag name is `a`. `href` is an attribute.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("a").length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to count all `A` tags inside the table?

Do something like

```
const table = document.getElementById("tableID");
const total = table.querySelectorAll('a').length;
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` does the job, you don't need `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Geoffroy I would advise to only ever use `getElementsByTagName` if you really, I mean, **really**, need a live `HTMLCollection` rather than a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and get the length of the collection:

```js
let linkCount = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tr > td > a').length

console.log(linkCount)
```

```html
<table id="tableID">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="..."> <a id=" " href="test1">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td style="..."> <a id=" " href="test2">123477</a>
      </td>
      <td style="..."> <a id=" " href="test3">1234557</a>
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#tableID a').length` would probably suffice unless OP has nested tables. `tableID.querySelectorAll('a').length` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mytable.querySelectorAll('a').length
```

```js
let linksNum = mytable.querySelectorAll('a').length;

console.log( linksNum );
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="...">
    <a id =" " href="test1">123456</a>
    </td>
    <td style="...">
    <a id =" " href="test2">123477</a>
    </td>
    <td style="...">
    <a id =" " href="test3">1234557</a>
    </td>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).This will select all the `HTMLAnchorElement` elements inside table ,you can change the parent to suit your condition

```js
var container = document.querySelector("table"); // parent
// if you have many tables you can do something like,to select particular table

//var container = document.getElementById("tableid"); // parent
var matches = container.querySelectorAll("a");
console.log(matches.length)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="...">
        <a id=" " href="test1">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td style="...">
        <a id=" " href="test2">123477</a>
      </td>
      <td style="...">
        <a id=" " href="test3">1234557</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There are no *"`href` elements"*. Only elements that have an `href` **attribute** like `HTMLAnchorElement` and `HTMLLinkElement`.